# How to programmatically get the number of users logged in on a linux machine?

Tags: c, linux, bash

I was wondering if it was possible to programmatically get the number of users logged in on a Linux machine in C? I did some researching and found out about utmp.h but since not all programs use utmp logging, I did not think it would be accurate enough. Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help.

EDIT: I apologize guys for not being more specific but when I say logged in users, I am referring to any logged in via shell. Basically what you get when you run the who command with no command line arguments.

Comment: Are `ftp` users considered "logged in?" How about HTML sessions on the web server? Define what you consider "logged in," since `utmp` isn't good for you. If it's shells, you may want to look for login shells (e.g., `-bash` instead of `bash`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <utmp.h>
#include <err.h>

#define NAME_WIDTH  8

    FILE *ufp;
    int numberOfUsers = 0;
    struct utmp usr;
    ufp = file(_PATH_UTMP);
    while (fread((char *)&usr, sizeof(usr), 1, ufp) == 1) {
    if (*usr.ut_name && *usr.ut_line && *usr.ut_line != '~') {
         numberOfUsers++;
        }
    }

    FILE *file(char *name)
    {
        FILE *ufp;

        if (!(ufp = fopen(name, "r"))) {
            err(1, "%s", name);
        }
        return(ufp);
    }
```

After a couple of days playing around with utmp, I figured it out. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Can you tell me, how to get logged out user count as well. i just want to get last logon time of all user. thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

You're targeting Linux, and you say you want to do what `who` does. If your software is not going to be distributed or is GPL licensed, you can just crib from the open source implementation of `who` that is running on your system.

But those are quite the restrictions. So, how can you find where to start without consulting source code? You can get a pretty good idea of where to look by running `nm` on the binary using `` nm `which who` ``. `who` calls very few external functions (34 under Mac OS X 10.6.4). The functions you are looking for must be among these. Likely candidates are `getutxent`, `utmpxname`, and `getpwuid`. You can check the man pages to validate this guess.

But first, why not try `apropos`/`man -k`? A quick search for "users" shows up the `users` utility, which just lists the logged-in users. (Note: This seems to be a BSDism, so you might not have it under Linux. Quick searches with `apropos` for relevant tools and functions are still a good idea.) `users` calls even fewer external functions (only 15), and of those, the only interesting one that overlaps with the interesting functions called by `who` is `getutxent`.

So, how about trying `getutxent`?

Comment: "You're targeting Linux, and you say you want to do what who does." Not exactly while who does provide some useful information, I am only interested in the number of users logged in.

Comment: @Error1f1f But you can derive that information from the information that `who` provides, so `who` exemplifies getting your hands on the information needed. If you can do what `who` does, you can do what you want to do, as demonstrated by @Alison R's shell pipeline that grabs the usernames, uniques them, and counts the unique results.

Answer (score 1):

The system call getutent is guaranteed to return a utmp like record regardless of the internal implementation.  So you can rely upon that api.

Answer (score 1):

utmp is your friend.

> man 5 utmp

Answer (score 1):

Not a C programmer, so I can't help in that arena, but can you have your program execute shell commands?

```
who | awk -F' ' '{print $1}' | sort -u | wc -l
```

Comment: No I can not have my program execute shell commands but this does produced the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utmp.h>
#include <string.h>
#define STREQ(A,B) (0==strcmp((A),(B)))

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct utmp *u;
    int count = 0;
    setutent();
    while ((u = getutent()) != NULL) {
        if (u->ut_line[0] == '~') continue;
        if (u->ut_user[0] && (!STREQ(u->ut_user, "LOGIN")) ) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    endutent();
    printf("%d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that regardless of utmp logging, you'll still have all the user information you want from that call.

What programs are you concerned about that don't use utmp logging as your linux may (or may not) use utmp logging.

And, as a commenter noted, what do you call 'logged in'?

Answer (score 0):

In bash:

```
$ ps aux | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort -d | uniq | wc -l
```

Answer (score -1):

linux shell command "who" maybe help you.